# Error in Stripe: 'createTokenWithCard(_:completion:)' is unavailable

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

Xcode told me that there is an error as follows: 'createTokenWithCard(_:completion:)' is unavailable

Here's the line of code:

```
Stripe.createTokenWithCard(creditCard, completion: { (token, stripeError) -> Void in
```

Can someone please correct my mistake?

I'm using Xcode 6.1

Answer (score 0):

That should fix it:

```
let StripePublishableKey = "YOUR_TEST_KEY"
let stpClient = STPAPIClient(publishableKey: StripePublishableKey)

stpClient.createTokenWithCard(creditCard, completion: {
                (token, stripeError) -> Void in

                if (stripeError == nil)
                {                      
                    // Your code here
                }
                else
                {
                    // Print error message here
                }
            })
```